# Estimating covariance matrix of irregularly updated time series

Tags: regression, time-series, covariance, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I would like to estimate the covariance matrix of returns from a set of time series that don't get updated regularly. To be precise, in my case all of the series fall into 2 classes. Class A gets updated daily and class B once every few days (but all at the same time). The underlying assumption is the actual hidden variables are a multidimensional random walk but some of the variables are revealed only at some points in time. Is there a standard method of modeling such data?

Answer (score 0):

Is the assumption that the 'hidden' states evolve on a daily timestep? If so it sounds like you need a State-Space model that allows the unobserved states to evolve on a regular timestep, even though observations may not occur on every time step. There are various software packages for setting up such models, for example the [`MARSS`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MARSS/index.html) R package or my own package, [`mvgam`](https://nicholasjclark.github.io/mvgam/). You may find [these applied time series analysis lectures](https://www.youtube.com/@SAFSTimeSeries/videos) useful for a broader overview.